# Insert data from table row into database based on checkbox state

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a form where you can type in information and choose several options. Based on what is chosen i would like to take id and create record in database.

```
 <form method = "post" action = "http://localhost:81/servisai/knygynas/insert_book.php">
   <input type = "submit" value = "Pridėti knygą">
      <tbody>
        <?php while($row = $resultb->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
          <tr>
            <td style="display:none"><input type = "text" name = "Autoriaus_id"></td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "Autoriaus_vardas" class="form-control" value = "<?php echo $row['Vardas']; ?>"></td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "Autoriaus_pavarde" class="form-control" value = "<?php echo $row['Pavarde']; ?>"></td>
            <td><input type = "checkbox" name = "myCheckbox" ></td>
          </tr>
        <?php endwhile ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
 </form>
```

I'm not sure how to choose which records to send to `insert_book.php` upon submitting 
I think it's supposed to do something with `if (isset($_POST['myCheckbox']))` but dont know where to go from here

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking, but maybe your problem is related to the fact that you are creating multiple form fields in your `while` loop which all have the same name. In PHP, you can give them array names (e.g. `<input type="text" name="autoriaus_vardas[1]">`) and get them sorted into arrays in `$_POST`. Using arrays without numbers probably won't work with checkboxes, as unchecked checkboxes are not submitted.

Comment: That's not the problem here. Each row has button for separate triggers. The idea is to have a form with several inputs. One section of them would be all inserted authord with a checkbox in each row. And so as each book can have more than one author, you could check whichever checkboxes you want. When you submit, the code should check which checkboxes are checked and create appropiate records for that. Or at least thats the idea i had about how to insert multiple authors to one book

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by following

```
<input type = "hidden" name = "Autoriaus_id[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>">
foreach($_POST['Autoriaus_id'] as $id){
   //do your stuffs here
}
```